# What does 'The Odd Couple' mean as a phrase?

Tags: meaning, names

> I'm watching tv series called [The odd Couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Odd_Couple) i tried to understand the meaning of that expression by watching it but i'm still not satisfied about the true meaning of it

- What does 'The odd Couple' mean?

My thoughts:

in brief The odd Couple means :

two people  with the following characteristics:

1. live in One appartment
2. with zero common
3. each one of him is divorced or has been dumped by his wife.
4. bachelor

update:

Two people who live together or are intertwined romantically that are grossly different from each other and would not normally get along under other circumstances. For instance, one person in the couple could be an introvert and the other an extrovert, although there are normally several distinct differences between the two partners to have the term "odd couple" used to describe a specific relationship.

An odd couple can also refer to two heterosexual bachelors living together, who are enjoying their singledom to the fullest.

- Also Known As: **incompatibility**, **roommates**, **strange bedfellows**

the picture can describe more:

[image: the odd couple]

Comment: It refers to an old comedy in which one of the apartment mates was a slob, and the other was compulsively neat.   That mixture of opposite personalities is "odd".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Odd_Couple may be useful as this was the title of a play initially.

Comment: It is *odd* that they are a *couple* given that they are so different from each other and have traits that make them get on each other's nerves. The 1965 play was made into a popular 1968 movie and soon after that a television series. The new show is a new version.

Comment: I rejected the edit of **bobthezealot** because I agree with ColleenV that [certain extensive edits are not good](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/2770/27803). @ʇolɐǝz ǝɥʇ qoq. And it still bugs me that I have to go to full site to track down and copy and paste a user name so cutesy as to be spelled with an upside down backwards font.

Comment: @GoDucks Sorry. Never knew that. Thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 4):

The word "couple" literally means two of something. We routinely refer to two people in a romantic relationship as a "couple". The word "odd" means unusual or strange.

The original 1968 movie was about two men who were sharing an apartment and who were wildly incompatible: one was fastidiously neat and the other very messy, one was culturally refined and the other very casual, etc. So they didn't fit together well as a couple. They were a strange pair, an "odd" "couple".

Apparently there's a 2015 TV series with the same title. I haven't seen it (I don't get broadcast TV any more), but from a description it appears to be a remake of the old movie.

(There was no indication in the movie that they were homosexual, by the way, they were just two friends sharing an apartment.)